# Convert float to integer in Rust

Tags: rust

```
double b = a / 100000;
b = (int) b;
b *= 100000;
```

How the above C code is converted to Rust? Especially the line #2 that rounds the number.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

> Especially the line #2 that rounds the number.

First of all: this is not true. To "round" a real number is to return the nearest integer. You just convert it to `int` which discards all the non-integer parts.

---

But here is the Rust equivalent of your exact code (assuming `a` has the type `f64`):

```
let b = a / 100_000.0;    // underscore in number to increase readability
let b = b as i64;
let b = b * 100_000;
```

Which, of course, can be written in one line, too:

```
let b = ((a / 100_000.0) as i64) * 100_000;
```

If you wanted to round instead of just taking the integer part, you can use the [`round`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.round) method of `f64`:

```
let b = ((a / 100_000.0).round() as i64) * 100_000;
```

---

Note that there are also [`trunc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.trunc), [`ceil`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.ceil) and [`floor`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.floor). You can use one of those methods to exactly control what happens instead of relying on the cast. [From the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/casting-between-types.html#numeric-casts) we can learn:

> Casting from a float to an integer will round the float towards zero.

This behavior is equivalent to `trunc`, but if the behavior does matter to you, you should use `trunc` to ...

1. ... express your intent in code
2. ... have valid semantics even if the Rust compiler changes the cast semantics

Answer (score 17):

To cast a float to an integer, you can use [`as`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/casts.html). For example:

```
let b = (a / 100000.0) as i64;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of round in Rust.
You have to write numeric constants right the type they are:
for example if d is f64 and you want to multiply it by 10 the right convention is to write:
d * 10.0
instead of:
d * 10

and explicitly define the type of your variable to make the round function available in this cases.

```
let a = 2e50;
let b : f64 = a / 100000.0;
let c = b.round() as i64;
println!("{}", c);
```

Comment: `b` is still a float, not an integer.