# Why does .parse() convert "42" to f64 but fails convert "42.0" to i32?

Tags: rust

Why and how does this line work:

```
let guess: f64 = "42".parse().expect("Not a number!");
```

But this does not?

```
let guess: i32 = "42.0".parse().expect("Not a number!");
```

Resulting in:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Not a number!: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }'
```

What is the correct way to parse "float" &str to integer?

**Update:**

I found this to work:

```
let guess: i32 = "42.0".parse::<f64>().expect("Not a number!") as i32;
```

However I don't understand the mechanics of how it works and if it is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're calling is actually `let guess: i32 = "42.0".parse::<i32>();`.

However, `"42.0"` is not a correct representation of an `i32`.

According to the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse):

> Because `parse` is so general, it can cause problems with type
>   inference. As such, `parse` is one of the few times you'll see the
>   syntax affectionately known as the 'turbofish': `::<>`. This helps the
>   inference algorithm understand specifically which type you're trying
>   to parse into.

The correct solution which you've already found is indeed to hint at the parser that the string is the representation of a float:

```
"42.0".parse::<f64>()
```

Comment: I would note that annotating the type of the left hand side is generally sufficient to avoid using the turbofish operator (and more concise). Here it's really an edge case, wanting to parse as a float and truncate the data.

Comment: Note that given the string `"42.1"`, the proposed solution will silently truncate it to `42`, which may or may not be desirable depending on your application. In some cases, you may want to check that the parsed float really represents an integer before converting.

Comment: @Jmb Which is why OP should use  `trunc`, `ceil` or `floor` to express their intent explicitely, instead on relying on the default behaviour (which is currently equivalent to trunc, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37508518/393701).