# Why do I get the error "the type of this value must be known in this context" when parsing a string to a number?

Tags: types, rust

I'm not trying to write sophisticated code, I just want to understand what is (or is not) going on here. I checked other questions but they all had complicated situations and I think this situation is the simplest so far.

I have the following code:

```
let one_step: f32 = "4.0".parse().unwrap();
let extra_step: u32 = one_step as u32;

println!("{:?}", extra_step);
```

The way I see it, we have a `&str`, we parse it to a `f32` and unwrap it. Then we convert the `f32` to a `u32`.

Why can't I just do this? Isn't this, practically, the same thing?

```
let single_step: u32 = "4.0".parse().unwrap() as u32;

println!("{:?}", single_step);
```

If I try to run this code, I get this error:

```
error[E0619]: the type of this value must be known in this context
 --> src/main.rs:6:27
  |
6 |     let single_step: u32 = "4.0".parse().unwrap() as u32;
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It looks like something requires us to break the operation into two chunks.

Comment: Highly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27043268/1233251 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/47178016/1233251

Comment: It is good practice to make a reproducible example in the [Rust Playground](//play.rust-lang.org), so that it can be run by everyone.

Comment: Also, yes, naming conventions are in the [Rust API guidelines](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing is that `parse` isn't just defined for `f32`. `parse` can define all kind of types (specifically any type that implements `FromStr`). So how does Rust know that `parse` should return `f32` and not for some other type?

In your first example it knows this because `oneStep` is declared to have type `f32`, so Rust can infer that it should call `parse` with `f32` as its type argument. In the second example `f32` isn't mentioned anywhere in the code, so Rust couldn't possibly figure it out.

Instead of inferring the type argument from the type of a variable, you can also pass it directly. That way it will work in a single step:

```
let singleStep: u32 = "4.0".parse::<f32>().unwrap() as u32;
```

Comment: where can I find more info about the "turbofish" ::<> ? The parse documentation had just some light info about it and google didn't help much

Comment: @OmarAbid It's just a somewhat strange syntax to pass type arguments. `parse` is defined as `parse<T>() {...}` and `parse::<f32>` is a way to explicitly say that `T` should be `f32`. The more intuitive syntax `parse<f32>` would have led to grammar ambiguities with the `<` and `>` operators, so the "turbofish" was introduced instead.

Comment: I don't get it. parse is not getting any arguments. But we are here talking about the return type?

Comment: @OmarAbid The point here is that Rust can infer parameter types from its "surroundings", not just from passed arguments. If we do `let x: i32 = "5".parse()?;`, the compiler can infer that `T` is `i32`. Regarding the turbofish, there is a brief mention in [`Iterator#collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect), where it is also commonly used.

Comment: @OmarAbid It is getting type arguments. As I said `parse` is defined as `parse<T>() -> T {...}` (except I accidentally left out the `-> T` in my previous comment). So we have 0 value arguments (`()`), but one type argument `<T>`. Some times type arguments can be inferred, but when they can't, you'll have to supply them manually.